# Upload profile picture based on gender

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a registration form with two radio buttons "male" and "female" my registration form works fine, but what I am having trouble with is uploading a profile picture based on the users gender selection. Any suggestions on how to imply this? 
This is the code from the form

```
<div align ="center">Gender: </div>
        </label> <br/>
        Male &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="gender" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Female &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="gender" />
```

Comment: what do mean by **uploading a profile picture based on the users gender selection** . You want to process image and check wheather it is male or female ?

Comment: @A.J I want the users profile picture to be a male avatar if male was checked in the registration form, and a female avatar if female was checked. does that make it a little more clear I hope?

Comment: Yes it did. Give me minute i will create a reference fiddle for you.

Comment: Is this an account creation form? On the server I assume you'd want an if statement seeing what gender was sent through POST and then insert their avatar into the database as the link to the image, like `domain.com/images/male.jpg`

Comment: @frosty How would I put the images in my database based on male and female? I am still a beginner with PHP/Mysql. I would appreciate it if you can give me more details on how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to have them check a gender box and then have a corresponding avatar show up on their profile page after they select a gender, then you need to store two images on your server in a public directory such as `site.com/images/male.png` and `site.com/images/female.png`. When you load the profile, you could use the following to select the corresponding picture.

```
if ($gender == 'male')
    $src = '/images/male.png';
else
    $src = '/images/female.png';

echo sprintf("<img alt=\"avatar\" src=\"%s\" />", $src);
```

Comment: I am still a beginner with Mysql and server stuff. how do I store the images? should I create a column named "gender" and store them in it?

Comment: They are files, just like your php code. Just put them on the server the same way you are putting your files on there.

Comment: Sorry I have over-thought out your answer !

Comment: It is giving me the error "Undefined index gender" I have my images on my server and have implied the code you have handed me into my profile page.

Comment: when you load the profile page, I assume you are querying a database and using a record from a table. I do not know how you are doing that, so I made a generic `$gender` variable. To go from your form to the profile page, you could pull the value for $_POST['gender'], but that will only work if you always use that form to get to the profile page which I doubt is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is reference [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5vpxfy0/), modify code as per your requirement.

```js
var male = new Image();
male.src = "https://slm-assets1.secondlife.com/assets/7232381/lightbox/byron1mainwide.jpg?1361771089";

var female = new Image();

female.src = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NgUohxAEzYQ/UDKsBYpDRmI/AAAAAAAAAcs/_anEWtBS7Ms/s1600/Female%2BVulcan%2BAvatar%2BPicture.jpg";

$("input[name='gender']").change(function() {

  if ($("input[type='radio']:checked").val() == "male") {
    $("#profile").html(male)
  } else {
    $("#profile").html(female)
  }
})
```

```css
#profile {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black
}
#profile img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center">Gender:</div>
</label>
<br/>Male &nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Female &nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />

<div id="profile"></div>
```

Update, Change `img` Tag:

Create a `change` event on radio button, check if male or female is checked and change image src accordingly.

```js
var imageTag = document.getElementById('profile')

$("input[name='gender']").change(function() {

  if ($("input[type='radio']:checked").val() == "male") {
    imageTag.src = "https://slm-assets1.secondlife.com/assets/7232381/lightbox/byron1mainwide.jpg?1361771089"
  } else {
    imageTag.src = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NgUohxAEzYQ/UDKsBYpDRmI/AAAAAAAAAcs/_anEWtBS7Ms/s1600/Female%2BVulcan%2BAvatar%2BPicture.jpg"
  }
})
```

```css
#profile {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center">Gender:</div>
</label>
<br/>Male &nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Female &nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />

<img id="profile"></img>
```

Comment: This is sort of what I am looking for, but since the gender selection is in the form registration how would I imply this code on the Profile page of the user?

Comment: Can you share your form code? I mean how are you displaying profile pic. Is it div with background or just `img` tag?

Comment: on the profile page the image is placed just the img tag .No div 

The registration form is a simple registration form asking for name, email, username, etc.. and GENDER.

Comment: it did not work, I believe that it is not getting the value of the radio buttons from the registration form .

Comment: Have yu given value to your radio buttons?

Comment: n you r using jquery ryt?

Comment: Yes as you have it value="male" and value="female" and Yes I am using jquery.
This is my image tag on my profile page

<img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="" id="profile">

and this is the jquery that you gave me 

var imageTag = document.getElementById('profile')

$("input[name='gender']").change(function() {

  if ($("input[type='radio']:checked").val() == "male") {
    imageTag.src = "C:\wamp\www\startbootstrap-creative-1\img\male.png"
 "C:\wamp\www\startbootstrap-creative-1\img\female.png"
  } else {
    imageTag.src = ""
  }
})

I just adjusted the image source

Comment: @motazjalil: don't give path of image from `C` drive. Try keeping the pictures in same folder and just giving the name of image

Comment: I changed the image source and still nothing, and I am not getting any errors . :-(